# showing dropdown value from json

Tags: jquery, html, json

i've html:

```html
<div id="div_bahan" class="form-group div_bahan">
  <label for="images" class="col-md-3 control-label">Bahan</label>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="col_bahan">
    <select name="bahan[]" id="bahan" class="form-control">
      <option value="0">--pilih--</option>
      <?php
        $qry = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bahan");
        while ($bahan = $qry->fetch_array()) {
          $qry2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM warna WHERE id_warna='$bahan[id_warna]'");
          $warna = $qry2->fetch_array();
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $bahan['id_bahan']; ?>"><?php echo $bahan['id_bahan']; ?> - <?php echo $bahan['nm_bahan'] . ' Warna ' . $warna['nm_warna']; ?></option> 
      <?php
        }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 addbahan" id="addbahan">
    <b onclick="addBahan()"  class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-flat"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Tambah bahan</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

when i edit action, the html get data from json.

This json :

```
{
  "bahan": [{
    "id_bahan": "4",
    "nm_jenis": "katun",
    "nm_warna": "merah",
    "nm_bahan": "Bhn Jeans 04",
    "stok_bahan": "5",
    "no": 1
  }, {
    "id_bahan": "1",
    "nm_jenis": "katun",
    "nm_warna": "merah",
    "nm_bahan": "Bhn Gamis 01",
    "stok_bahan": "21",
    "no": 2
  }, {
    "id_bahan": "3",
    "nm_jenis": "katun",
    "nm_warna": "hijau",
    "nm_bahan": "Bhn Jaket 02",
    "stok_bahan": "12",
    "no": 3
  }, {
    "id_bahan": "2",
    "nm_jenis": "spandex",
    "nm_warna": "kuning",
    "nm_bahan": "Bhn koko 01",
    "stok_bahan": "3",
    "no": 4
  }]
}
```

how to i edit action and showing data in `select value` ?

Comment: where is `addBahan()` so that i could finally trace id_bahan, nm_jenis? This is so funny. lmao.

Comment: oh, i forget it, this is addBahan()      function addBahan() {
                $("#div_bahan").clone().insertAfter("div#div_bahan:last");
                $(".addbahan").not(':first').remove();
                return false;

Comment: this is my code now, but its just showing one dropdown  $.each(data.bahan, function (i, v) {
                    $('#bahan').val(v.id_bahan);
                });

Answer (score 0):

Use this to add option tags to the `select` element:

```
$(data.bahan).each(function(i, e) {
    var name = e.id_bahan+' - '+e.nm_bahan+' Warna '+e.nm_warna,
        o = new Option(name, e.id_bahan);

    $('#bahan').append(o);
});
```